# OSX appearing some message after su - root

Tags: macos, terminal, root

Whenever after i switch to root:
`su - root`

and when i become `root` in the terminal, it is showing:
`-sh: /Applications/XCODE: No such file or directory`

Where is this message appear from, please?
Where can i find it?

Comment: Does root have a `.bash_profile` (perhaps `/var/root/.bash_profile`)?  If so, that sounds like where the issue lies...

Comment: yes, root have it. but nothing inside.

Comment: Anything in `/etc/profile` that looks like the issue?

Comment: awwww ya. it is `PATH=$PATH;/Applications/XCODE` .. Should i remove it?

Comment: Yes; you don't need to add Xcode.app to `$PATH` as that is what `xcode-select` is for.  Plus that semi-colon is Windows-format EEEK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from `trojanfoe`.

1. To check the `/var/root/.bash_profile`
2. To check the `/etc/profile`

Thanks!